# Using 'name' attribute in <a> tag to use in $_POST

Tags: php, html, mysql

The field values are taken from the MySQL database.

On clicking the submit button, it should echo the text-field value and the name of the file in `<a>` tag.

```
$files_of_signed_in_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM uploaded_files WHERE user_id = '$_SESSION[userid]' ");
echo "Self uploaded files<br>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($files_of_signed_in_user)) {
  echo "<form enctype = 'multipart/form-data' method='post'>"
  . "<a name='file_name' href='uploaded_files/".$row['file_name']."'>".$row['file_name']."</a>"
  . "<input type='text' name='Emailid_to_be_sent' placeholder='Emailid' /> "
  . "<input type='submit' name='share_file' value='Send' /> </form></br>";
}
```

When submit is clicked, the text input and filename are to be echoed

```
if (isset($_POST['share_file'])) { 
  echo $_POST['Emailid_to_be_sent'];
  echo $_POST['file_name'];          
}
```

I am aware that anchor tag does not support `name` attribute.

Could you let me know how this can be achieved?

Comment: I am aware that <a> tag does not support 'name' attribute.
Could let me know how can my problem be solved?

Comment: <a> supports name and it makes it anchor, but however only fields can be posted (input, select, textarea, etc.) HTML does not posts links. Use `<input name="file_name" type="hidden" value="uploaded_files/...." />` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hidden input field instead:

```
<?php

 $files_of_signed_in_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM uploaded_files WHERE user_id = '$_SESSION[userid]' ");
        echo "Self uploaded files<br>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($files_of_signed_in_user)) {
            echo "<form enctype = 'multipart/form-data' method='post'>"
                    . "<a name='file_name' href='uploaded_files/".$row['file_name']."'>".$row['file_name']."</a>"
                    . "<input type='text' name='Emailid_to_be_sent' placeholder='Emailid' /> "
                    . "<input type='hidden' name='file_name' placeholder='" . htmlentities($row['file_name']) . "' /> "
                    . "<input type='submit' name='share_file' value='Send' /> </form></br>";
        }
```

Hidden fields aren't displayed to the user but will be submitted with the rest of the form.

Answer (score 0):

`anchor` tag is not a `form` input element.
use `hidden` input field to store the file name.

```
. "<a name='file_name' href='uploaded_files/".$row['file_name']."'>".$row['file_name']."</a>"
. "<input type='hidden' name='file_name' value=".$row['file_name']." /> "
. "<input type='text' name='Emailid_to_be_sent' placeholder='Emailid' /> "
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a file name or path in hidden html element because is dangerous. In the second file get the file names with php or store that in session or $GLOBALS

Comment: I see it works with the hidden input.But, could you please elaborate on why is this dangerous and how can I use $GLOBALS in my problem?
It will be helpful if you could share the code for it too.